Turning a list of list into a list of tuples
I have a list of list
ll = [["ab", "cd", "ef"], ["x", "y", "z"]]

and I want to get out of it a list of tuples, [{"ab", "cd", "ef"}, {"x", "y", "z"}].
Of course I can do this with a comprehension,
lt=[]
for le <- ll, into: lt do
  List.to_tuple(le)
end

but is there a more "functional" approach to do this? I tried
lt = List.map(ll, fn(le) -> List.to_tuple(le) end) # NOT POSSIBLE!

but I get an UndefinedFunctionError. Indeed, List does not seem to have a map function.

Do you want Enum.map/2?

Indeed, Enum.map(ll, fn x -> List.to_tuple(x) end) seems to work. If you post this (or a more elegant version) as answer, I will then accept it.

In Elixir, many of the standard functional-programming helpers are in the Enum module, like Enum.map/2.
lt = Enum.map(ll, fn le -> List.to_tuple(le) end)
#    ^^^^ (not List)

Since you're directly invoking a single-argument function as the thing to map, you can directly pass a reference to the function, rather than wrapping it in a lambda.
lt = Enum.map(ll, &List.to_tuple/1)

Finally, in some contexts, it may be idiomatic to use pipeline syntax.  This is especially true if, say, the original list is the return from another function, or if you need to do some post-processing on the result.  The left-hand side of the pipeline is passed as the first argument to the function call on the right-hand side.
lt = ll |> Enum.map(&List.to_tuple/1)

